# PHP cannot find a file in a sub Namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I want to use an interface located in a sub namespace but PHP gives an error. What's wrong with this code? These are located in 2 different files.

```
<?php

namespace Application\Web;

use Application\Web\Interfaces\LearningInterface;

class Learning implements LearningInterface
{
public function __construct()
{

}

public function multiArray()
{
    $a = array(
        array("key1" => 940, "key2" => 343),
        array("key1" => 232, "key2" => 422),
        array("key1" => 4645, "key2" => 654)
    );

    print_r($a); die;
}
```

}

This is the interface which I wanna use inside my class.

```
<?php

namespace Application\Web\Interfaces;

interface LearningInterface
{
public function multiArray();
}
```

It gives a Fatal error interface not found[image: Project codebase image]

Comment: Can you post your autoloader?

Comment: I don't have an autoloader. I just wanted to use this interface in this Learning file as a test. Will it not work if I use the "use statement" as above?

Comment: It will not look outside of the current file unless you specifically set it up to do so. If you dont want to use an autoloader, you can require the file at the top of your code, after the namespace declaration. However i would advise that you look into autloading.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: I know about require and require_once etc. But I thought I can use it like this. Thanks for the help.